# All purpose image swap function

Tags: javascript, image, swap

Ok, I am new to JavaScript so please keep that in mind when you answer.  What I am looking for is a function that I can use that will enable me to click an image, then click another image and swap their positions on the page. For example I have a 3x4 table with 12 separate images, I click on 'image1' and then click 'image3' and the two swap. The only solutions I have found deal with swapping an image with a specified image, this is not what I need. Hope this makes sense.

Any suggestions and solutions are welcomed to help me learn! Thank you!
Also, I would like this to be 100% JavaScript and not jQuery.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th id="pos1"> <img src="pic_01.gif" id="pic1" onclick="imageSwap()" alt="" border=       height=100 width=100></img> </th>
    <td id="pos2"> <img src="pic_02.gif" id="pic2" alt="" border= height=100 width=100>     </img></td>
    <td id="pos3"> <img src="pic_03.gif" alt="" border= height=100 width=100></img></td>
</tr>
```

Attempted JS:

```
imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'pic_01.gif';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'pic_02.gif';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'pic_03.gif';

etc etc...

var a
var b
function imageSwap(){
 getElementById.src = a
```

Not sure at all what to do for the swap itself

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-authoring service.  You're expected to have tried something first yourself....

Comment: I would've maybe authored some code if you at least let me use jQuery…

Comment: what behavior do you expect if images are of different size and the one place dosen't have enough space for swapped image..put it behind, over, or make space..if make space what logic needs to be followed

Comment: I agree with Ethan, if you did your own research and used google you'd find many answers in the first five results.  Also if you say you looked but did not find anything the nicest thing I'd have to say is "you did the search wrong"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was bored and felt like being nice, so here's an example of [image swapping](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/PReuS/5/), even though you made no attempt. Try to avoid being distracted by the cute kittens.

The part of the code that matters is the script:

```
var position = null,
target = null;

$("img").click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "border"){
        $(this).toggleClass("border");
        target = null;
        position = null;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $(this).toggleClass("border");
        if (position == null){
            position = $(this).attr("src");
            $(this).toggleClass("position");
        }
        else{
            target = $(this).attr("src");
            $(this).attr("src", position);
            $(".position").attr("src", target)
                .toggleClass("position");
            $(".border").toggleClass("border");
            position = null;
            target = null;
        }
    }
})
```

The `<html>` is just a set of images and the CSS just adds some margins and the border for the image you click. In short, the code checks whether the image has been selected. If it already has a selection border and you click it again, it deselects the image. If the image clicked hasn't been selected, it checks whether a position has been set. If a position has been set, it swaps the target (the image just clicked) with the image previously clicked. Otherwise, it sets the image clicked as the position (and then the next click will cause the images to swap).

Comment: Lol. Thank you, you are appreciated! This gives me something to dissect and learn from.  I updated with code.  Well more of where my train of thought was going than actual code

Comment: @swam I would really look into jQuery. I learned jQuery, then backtracked and learned all the little annoying things in JavaScript. I found it to be the easiest way.